# MongoDB using not and equal to

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Problem**

if the phone does not exist then update the phone otherwise show an error **phone already exist**

Same case as when a user register on the site. After registration, if he wants to change the email if the email does not exist then update its email

Hope you guys understand what I want

**Data**

```
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0"),
    "active" : true,
    "phone" : "+447911123456",
    "user" : ObjectId("5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-24T08:19:06.098Z"),
    "__v" : 0

},
{

    "_id" : ObjectId("5fbe06950220f92c5b781e4d"),
    "active" : true,
    "phone" : "+447911123457",
    "user" : ObjectId("5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-11-24T08:19:06.098Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Code**

```
let phoneExist = await Agent.findOne({ 
    $and: [{
        user: { $ne: ObjectId('5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce') }
    }, {
        _id: { $ne: '5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0' }
    }],
    phone: '+447911123457'
});

// console.log(phoneExist)
if(!phoneExist) {
    const agent = await Agent.findByIdAndUpdate('5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0', phone, { new: true, runValidators: true });

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: agent
    });        
} else {
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Phone already exist', 409));
}
```

Comment: first of you are totally misusing `$and`... then you query is not completely clear as if what result do you want actually? In your code you put `user: { $ne: '5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce' }` due to which both of your objects got eliminated. And `!phoneExist` becomes true so it enters the `if` block instead of `else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where I understood, you want to check if provided `phone` already exist against the specific `_id` and `user`. If not exist, update it, otherwise throw error.

In this case, it is much simpler:

```
/* if you are querying on "_id" field, you don't need anything else (i.e. "user") */
const agent = await Agent.findById('5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0');

/* but if you still want this, then do it this way */
// const agent = await Agent.findOne({_id: '5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0', user: '5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce'});

if (agent.phone != '+447911123457') {
    agent.phone = '+447911123457';
    await agent.save();
    
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: agent
    });
} else
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Phone already exist', 409));
```

---

**EDIT**

SQL:

> SELECT * FROM agents WHERE user != {user} AND phone = {phone}

MongoDb:

```
await Agent.findOne({
    "user": { $ne: 'enter user here' }
    "phone": 'enter phone here'
});
```

that's it! :)

---

**Last EDIT**
So according to your ( @Adam's ) solution, it should look somehow like:

```
const phoneExist = await Agent.findOne({
    "_id":   { $ne: ObjectId(req.params.id) },
    "user":  ObjectId(req.user.id),
    "phone": data.phone
});

if (! phoneExist) {
    const agent = await Agent.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {phone: data.phone}, {new: true});
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        data: agent
    });
} else
    return next(new ErrorResponse('Phone already exist', 409));
```

Comment: In this case, multiple phones insert against different IDs

Comment: give it a shot. If you get any issue leave a comment here

Comment: Not working. error: E11000 duplicate key error collection index: phone_1

Comment: this code works fine. I've tested it myself. But if you're having issue, kindly elaborate your query in detail.

Comment: According to your data, what you need?

Comment: I need to insert a unique phone into my collection. How I convert this SQL query into MongoDB select * from agents where user != {user} and phone = {phone}.

Comment: now you mentioned your question clearly in contrast of SQL query... I've updated my answer. See "EDIT"

Comment: As you mentioned in your description.  " if provided phone already exists against the specific _id and user". I wanted to check if the phone already exist against the user then show an error

Comment: after alot of discussion this solution works for me.   let phoneExist = await Agent.find({user : ObjectId(req.user.id), 
  phone : data.phone, _id: { $ne: ObjectId(req.params.id) }})

  if(phoneExist.length == 0 || phoneExist == null){ // code }

Comment: but this one is too different from the SQL query

Comment: Sorry for sharing the wrong SQL. But glad for your effort

Comment: no issues :) See my updated answer. I think its according to your need

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
let phoneExist = await Agent.findOne({ user: ObjectId('5fb64b808232c9983eab41ce') } },
{ _id: ObjectId('5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0'), phone: '+447911123457'});

console.log(phoneExist)
if(!phoneExist){

const agent = await Agent.findByIdAndUpdate('5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0', phone, {
new: true,
runValidators: true
});


 res.status(200).json({
success: true,
data: agent
});


}
else{
return next(new ErrorResponse('Phone already exist', 409));
}
```

Comment: I already added this var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Comment: Use it in `_id: { $ne: '5fbcc1fa2afc3e556c32fce0' }`

Comment: let phoneExist = await Agent.findOne({ $and: [ { user: { $ne:ObjectId(req.user.id) } },
  { _id: { $ne: ObjectId(req.params.id) } } ], phone: data.phone });


**Still same issue**

Comment: What `console.log(phoneExist)` prints?

Comment: You need to remove `!` or `$ne`. Because your query show phone phone not exist. Pay more attention to it and you will get it.

Comment: I want to write this query in mongodb.

select * from agents where user != {user} and phone = {phone}.

Your code not working

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is a new record, not insert. If I enter the phone that already exist it shows an error. But when I add a new phone which does not exist. it still gives the same error **phone already exist**